# Unexpected behavour when making array of 2D arrays, of similar dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

**MWE:**

```
def showArrayOfList(a,b,c):
    wlist = [np.zeros((szNext,szThis)) for (szThis,szNext) in [(a,b),(b,b),(b,b),(b,c)]]

    print "wlist:", map(np.shape,wlist)

    wArray = np.asarray(wlist)
    print "wArray:", map(np.shape,wArray)
    print "shape wArray:", shape(wArray)
```

`np.zeros` can be substituted for any other matrix function that returns a matrix given a shape

The output from the following is what I expect (and get):

```
In[1]: ShowArrayOfList(1,4,5)
Out[1]: wlist: [(4, 1), (4, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4)]
wArray: [(4, 1), (4, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4)]
shape wArray: (4,) #An array of 4 references(?), to arrays of various sizes

In[2]: ShowArrayOfList(5,5,5)
Out[2]: wlist: [(5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5)]
wArray: [(5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5)]
shape wArray: (4, 5, 5) #4 arrays of shape (5,5)
```

But for inputs of the form `a!=b` and `b==c` things are completely different

```
Int[3]: showArrayOfList(6,5,5)
Out[3]: wlist: [(5, 6), (5, 5), (5, 5), (5, 5)]
wArray: [(5,), (5,), (5,), (5,)] #Where did my second Dimension Go?
shape wArray: (4, 5)


Int[4]: showArrayOfList(2,4,4)
Out[4]:
wlist: [(4, 2), (4, 4), (4, 4), (4, 4)]
wArray: [(4,), (4,), (4,), (4,)] #Where did my second Dimension Go?
shape wArray: (4, 4)
```

This cause a very hard to find bug for me,
With some thought, I think it has something to do with the Broadcasting system.

**I would like what is going on, explained. (I have a blurry notion in my head)**

---

For reference the reason I am making a array of arrays is for subtraction: 
`wArray=wArray-dWs` is a lot clearer to read than than 
`wList=[w-dW, (w,dW) in zip(wList,dWs)]`

Comment: In version `1.9.0dev`, `wArray` in the last two cases is an array of `None`.  If I try it interactively I get `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,5) into shape (5)`.  Whether this is bug in my version or not, this is not a reliable way of constructing an array.  I think `wArray` should always have shape `(4,)`, regardless of `a,b,c`.  Not sometimes 2d or 3d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply printing out the arrays should fairly quickly allow you too see what happened.

As to the question of where did the last dimension go. Since the size of that dimension has variable length. Numpy wont create a new dimension for it, it will simply create an array of objects (where the object is a list) of varying length.

In the `showArrayOfList(2,4,4)` case your array looks like this:

First row:
`[array([ 0.,  0.]) array([ 0.,  0.]) array([ 0.,  0.]) array([ 0.,  0.])]`

second to fourth row:
 `[array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]) array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
 array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]) array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])]`

Answer (score 0):

A more consistent way of creating `wArray` is to initialize it to a `(4,)` object array, and fill it term by term:

```
n = len(wlist)
wArray = np.empty((n,), dtype='O')
for i in range(n):
    wArray[i] = wlist[i]
```

This isn't as pretty as `asarray(wlist)`, but it splits the 3 dimensions in the same 1,2 manner regardless of what `a,b,c` are.