# Fast array/list type for holding numpy ndarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a lot of list of numpy ndarrays, of different sizes, in my code.
(I also have lists of lists of numpy ndarrays, but that is less issue as those lists are small (<5 elements).)

I have learn that [ndarrays of ndarrays of different dimention, doesn't really workout.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308785/unexpected-behavour-when-making-array-of-2d-arrays-of-similar-dimention).

Operations I tend to do on it:

- Accessing/Writing it in reverse. (Currently writing is done by reversing the list twice)
- Appending to it
- Applying functions on the contained ndarrays, eg summing 2 lists of ndarrrays elementwise, multipliplying by -1 etc.

I currently am manipulating them with the following functions (as well as more direct operations)

```
def uniop_nested(func,o_list):
    def inner(i_list):
    ¦   if isinstance(i_list[0],np.ndarray):
    ¦   ¦   ¦return map(func, i_list)
    ¦   else:
    ¦   ¦   ¦return map(inner, i_list)
    return inner(o_list)



def binop_nested(func, o1, o2):
    if not isinstance(o1,np.ndarray):
    ¦   return [binop_nested(func, i1, i2)  for (i1,i2) in zip(o1,o2)]
    else:
    ¦   return func(o1,o2)



def add_nested(s1,s2):
    return binop_nested(np.add,s1,s2)
```

I'm finding from profiling, that these lists are an issue.

Comment: Are your ndarrays all 1d arrays? Are they all of the same number of dimensions?

Comment: No. Some are 2D. Within a list of ndarrays often (in the most performance critical parts) they are all 2D. In other parts they are a mix of 2d and 1d, and in some parts as mention it is a list of lists of ndarrays of different dimentions (but i don't really care about hte preformance of that last part)

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about your data, but it isn't often that I run into cases where I have a collection of data with differing dimensionalities yet want to apply the same operation to each. Maybe there is a better way to split your data into separate groups so you can use better data structures...

For example, if you could separate all of your 1d arrays out and keep them together, you could store them in a 2d array with masked entries.

Comment: For example, I have a list of matrix weight error derivatives, and I want to subtract them (after multiplying by a learning rate) from my weight matrixs for gradient decent.

Comment: Are you sure that the overhead is from the `list` and not from creating lots of small `ndarray`s?  Python lists are ideally suited to what you're describing. (i.e. an append-able container for arbitrary objects) However, if you're profiling things based on lots of small `ndarray`s, you'll mostly see the overhead of array creation (which is relatively slow).

Comment: What you're doing looks quite efficient at first glance.  Can you give us a bit more context?  Are all of the small arrays subsets of some larger array?  Basically, there's a fair amount of overhead anytime you're working with lots of individual small `ndarray`s. If there's any way you can group things into larger arrays, it may be worthwhile.