# How to do numpy structural arrays

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble getting my head around structural arrays in numpy.

lets say i have

- two lists of tuples (to use native python types). `foo_list` and `bar_list`.
- `len(foo_list)==len(bar_list)` The lists are the same length
- for all i,j: `len(foo_list[i])==len(foo_list[j])` and `len(bar_list[i])==len(bar_list[j])`  all the tuples in each list are the same length. But these lengths are not known til runtime (so I can't hard code them into a dtype string)
- for all i,j: `len(foo_list[i])!=len(bar_list[j])` The tuples in different list has different lengths

How do I zip these two together into as structure array?
It seems like specifying the dtype is going to involve a mass of string manipulation after i do things like examine the structure myself.
I did try this once it was not nice code, so i figure there must be a better way to do it.

Currently I am doing: 
Currently my solution is to zip them and pass them to a `numpy.asarray`

, but that has weird consequences.
It makes a 2D array of objects and those objects are arrays.
If you slice it you end up with a array of arrays - not a 2D array.

Example data:

```
foo_list = [(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
 (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
 (0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0),
 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0),
 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)]
bar_list = [(0.56885990540494535, 0.54212235514533669),
 (-1.0024727291757354, 0.75636919036826),
 (1.0912423038752346, 0.66209493674389353),
 (0.52256034116805239, 0.36499434352207855),
 (-1.6837689312941191, 0.90001803836488747),
 (-3.1590090289110528, -0.3383410738003263),
 (1.4080085734609102, -1.6283826051481185),
 (1.5037872498731264, 1.5673560444854553),
 (-2.271232989935922, 0.24542353558497185),
 (-1.9752557923680221, 0.07968567723276497)]
```

Comment: please post some sample data.

Comment: hpaulj: For a normal nump array, yes, but structure arrays should (as I understnad it) get around that problem

Comment: `foo_list` and `bar_list` can individually be made into arrays (size `(10,5)` and `(10,2)`).  What's the reason for combining them into a structured array?  It's not going to speed up any `numpy` calculations.  If you do combine them, what shape and dtype do you want it have?

Comment: They are logically not distinct lists. For example each item in foo_list is a label for a image represented by the the data in bar_list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308785 is another SO question about reliably constructing an array of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a structured array in which each structure has two fields, "foo" and "bar".  Each field is a 1-D array.  Here's one way to create such a structured array.

First get the lengths of the "foo" and "bar" fields:

```
In [26]: nfoo = len(foo_list[0])

In [27]: nbar = len(bar_list[0])
```

Create the `dtype` for the structured array.  It has two fields, "foo" and "bar".  Each field will contain an array of floating point values, with lengths `nfoo` and `nbar`, respectively.

```
In [28]: dt = np.dtype([('foo', np.float64, nfoo), ('bar', np.float64, nbar)])
```

Create the array with `np.array`, giving it the zipped lists and the new dtype.

```
In [29]: a = np.array(zip(foo_list, bar_list), dtype=dt)
```

`a` is a 1-D array with length 10:

```
In [30]: a.shape
Out[30]: (10,)

In [31]: a
Out[31]: 
array([([0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.5688599054049454, 0.5421223551453367]),
       ([1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-1.0024727291757354, 0.75636919036826]),
       ([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0912423038752346, 0.6620949367438935]),
       ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.5225603411680524, 0.36499434352207855]),
       ([0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [-1.683768931294119, 0.9000180383648875]),
       ([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [-3.159009028911053, -0.3383410738003263]),
       ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.4080085734609102, -1.6283826051481185]),
       ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.5037872498731264, 1.5673560444854553]),
       ([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [-2.271232989935922, 0.24542353558497185]),
       ([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [-1.975255792368022, 0.07968567723276497])], 
      dtype=[('foo', '<f8', (5,)), ('bar', '<f8', (2,))])
```

We can slice and dice `a` in many ways.

`a['foo']` is the entire 2-D array from `foo_list`:

```
In [32]: a['foo']
Out[32]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

`a['bar'][0, -1]` is the last column from the first row of `bar_list`:

```
In [33]: a['bar'][0,-1]
Out[33]: 0.54212235514533669
```

`a[0]['bar']` is the first row from `bar_list`.  (This could also be accessed as `a['bar'][0]`).

```
In [34]: a[0]['bar']
Out[34]: array([ 0.56885991,  0.54212236])
```

Because the individual data elements in the "foo" and "bar" fields are all of type `np.float64`, you can create a 2-D view of this data.  In the following, `v` is a 2-D array with shape (10, 7).

```
In [42]: v = a.view(np.float64).reshape(len(a), -1)

In [43]: v.shape
Out[43]: (10, 7)

In [44]: v[0]
Out[44]: 
array([ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,
        0.56885991,  0.54212236])

In [45]: v[0, -1]
Out[45]: 0.54212235514533669
```

But if a 2-D array is what you want, you don't need to create a structured
array.  You can create the 2-D array directly, in several ways.  For example,

```
In [46]: b = np.array([f+b for f, b in zip(foo_list, bar_list)])

In [47]: b.shape
Out[47]: (10, 7)

In [48]: b[0]
Out[48]: 
array([ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,
        0.56885991,  0.54212236])

In [49]: b[0, -1]
Out[49]: 0.54212235514533669
```

Comment: Can you address a[0][0]? ?

Comment: `a[0][0]` will give the first *row* of the 'foo' data.